# reverse grep from infile

Tags: awk, grep

I know it has been asked many times... but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this simple task. Datas are not sorted.

#### Sample data :

#### file_1

```
E-J1-N4  
D-J5-N7  
F-J1-N5  
E-J5-N8
```

#### file_2

```
E-J5-N8  
F-J5-N2  
E-J1-N4  
D-J5-N7    
F-J1-N5  
F-J5-N1  
F-J5-N12  
F-J5-N3
```

> (I edited the datas to better reflect my actual dataset, what seem to be causing problems are the Nxx, N12 here. As they are right know, datas are not easily sortable, I know I could format all my numbers to be N01 N02 ect... But if I could avoid that, it would be nice.)

So I simply need to print $names in `file_2` that are not in `file_1`

```
grep -vf file_1 file_2
```

does not work.

```
for name in `file_1`; do grep -v $name file_2; done
```

gives me a ton of output... (64 #names with duplicates). The loop without the `-v flag` does not work neither, it adds datas. (`wc -l` doesn't match)

So, why `grep -vf` not working ? Could it be a sorting problem ? Why the loop is not working and if it would, how could I reverse the `grep` in the `for loop` ?

As always, thanx a lot for looking ! I'm open to other solutions as well (`awk`, `python`).

Comment: `grep -vf file_1 file_2` works fine for me for your input files.

Comment: Yes, your grep works for me on my Mac OS X (which is BSD).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yes, command works if there is no Nxx in dataset, but with edited datas, I get an extra $name : F-J1-N5 in file_1 and in output of grep -vf ! Why ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
comm -1 -3 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2)
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] comm -1 -3 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2)
F-J5-N2
F-J5-N3
F-J6-N1
F-J6-N2
F-J6-N3
F-J6-N4
F-J6-N5
F-J6-N6
F-J6-N7
F-J6-N8
F-J8-N1
F-J9-N1
F-J9-N2
```

#### Update:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat ff1
E-J1-N4
D-J5-N7
F-J1-N5
E-J5-N8

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat ff2
E-J5-N8
F-J5-N2
E-J1-N4
D-J5-N7
F-J1-N5
F-J5-N1
F-J5-N12
F-J5-N3

[jaypal:~/Temp] comm -1 -3 <(sort ff1) <(sort ff2)
F-J5-N1
F-J5-N12
F-J5-N2
F-J5-N3
```

Comment: As they are, datas are not easily naturally sortable, from my point of view anyway... F-J9-Nxx vs F-J9-Nx is the cause.

Comment: So you want the output data to be sorted as well? With your new data set, I get the 4 records that are not present in File_1. Updated answer added to original post

Comment: interesting... I get 5 records from your comm command : comm -1 -3 <(sort 1) <(sort 2) : F-J1-N5, F-J5-N1, F-J5-N12, F-J5-N2, F-J5-N3. Why would your command gives right output ?

Comment: Looks like your files have special characters. Do `cat -vet` and see if there is any `space`, `tab`, `carriage-return` which could be throwing it off. Especially look at the line with `F-J1-N5` line

Comment: wow... you are so right ! I had spaces in both files, now your command works. I'll check for special character in my dataset and test your command. Thanx !

Comment: Wow again... so simple and it works like a charm. I had spaces all around my dataset. Thank you very much Jaypal ! I couldn't imagine spaces causing all the trouble !!

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' file_1 file_2
```

Result:

```
F-J5-N2
F-J5-N3
F-J6-N1
F-J6-N2
F-J6-N3
F-J6-N4
F-J6-N5
F-J6-N6
F-J6-N7
F-J6-N8
F-J8-N1
F-J9-N1
F-J9-N2
```

Comment: Same here, with edited datas, I get an extra $name.awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' 1 2  
F-J5-N2  
F-J1-N5  
F-J5-N1  
F-J5-N12  
F-J5-N3

Comment: Your solution work as well, once I have removed spaces from my dataset... Thank you !

Comment: @Birei We can do `awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' file_{1,2}` … Less typing. :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution only works if there is not duplicate lines within file_2 **and** file_1 is a subset of file_2:

```
sort file_[12] | uniq -u
```

Explain: the sort command combines the two files, then sort them. The uniq command then only picked out those lines that are not duplicated, which means the ones in file_2, but not in file_1.

Note that if you replace the *-u* flag with *-d* then the output will consist of those lines that are duplicated, meaning appears in both files.

Comment: yes, thank you for your explanation. But again, my dataset is not easily sortable. If I can't get any script to work without sorting datas, I'll have to write a script to modify my datas so they'll be sortable....

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file_1 file_2
```

Comment: Good solution as well, thank you guy's, you are an invaluable resource !